# slime-call-defun equivalent in sly?

Tags: slime, sly

`Slime` [defines two commands](https://www.common-lisp.net/project/slime/doc/html/REPL.html): `slime-call-defun` and `slime-eval-last-expression-in-repl` which take the function name of where point is (or whatever) and copy it over to the REPL prompt and position point accordingly.

Is there such a functionality for `Sly` and how do I use it?
If not, is there some openly available elisp code, which I could use to achieve this?
If there is no such functionality available, which workflow is intended?

Answer (score 1):

Since no one answered, I've done a naive implementation. This is a community wiki answer in hope, the implementation evolves over time.

```
(defun my-sly-copy-call-to-repl ()
  "Copy name/symbol of toplevel sexp to sly-mREPL and select sly-mREPL."
  (interactive)
  (let (string
        replwin)
    (save-excursion 
      (beginning-of-defun)
      (forward-thing 'symbol 2)
      (setq string (format "(%s )" (thing-at-point 'symbol 'no-props))))
    (setq replwin (get-buffer-window (call-interactively #'sly-mrepl)))
    (with-selected-window replwin
      (insert string)
      (forward-char -1))))
```